# Piping to More Than One Location - PowerScript

Tags: powershell, output, pipe

I want to do something like this-

```
"Error array cleared." | Out-File $ErrorLog $InfoLog -Append
```

However it's not working. Is this possible without writing another line to output it to the other file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with a short function like this:

```
function Out-FileMulti {
  param(
    [String[]] $filePath
  )
  process {
    $text = $_
    $filePath | foreach-object {
      $text | out-file $_ -append
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

```
"Out-FileMultiTest" | Out-FileMulti "test1.log","test2.log"
```

(Writes the string "Out-FileMultiTest" to both test1.log and test2.log)

Comment: Interesting. So no native way to do it huh?

I'm not at all familiar with "Process" or "Param". I noticed you're really good at PowerShell things. Do you know of a site that'll help me get better at scripting via exercises or the like? Right now I'm just trying my hand at scripts that help automate things I do at work/home, but without any actual training (and no matter how much I Google) I find it hard to grasp new concepts.

Comment: Also, in regards to the answer, will this work for files created at run-time? I'm guessing not.

Comment: What does "files created at run-time" mean?

Comment: The logging files are created with the date stamp of the current day, so I set it to a variable- $DateStamp = (Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy). I can't seem to get your code to work using variables.

Comment: What does "can't seem to get your code to work using variables" mean? (Remember, I can't see your screen.)

Comment: `Function MultiOut
{
  Param
  (
    [String[]] $LogPath
  )
  Process 
  {
    $Text = $_
    $FilePath | ForEach-Object 
    {
      $Text | Out-File $_ -append
    }
  }
}`

Sorry if I obliterated your formatting there (no block code in comments?). Here's where I call the function-

`"Test" | MultiOut "$ErrorLog","$InfoLog"'
and
'"Test" | MultiOut $ErrorLog,$InfoLog

Comment: Here's my variables, I think it might be relevant-

$LogPath = ".\Logs"
$RootSource = ".\FileDirectory\PushRoot\*"
$DesktopSource = ".\FileDirectory\PushDesktop\*"
$RootDestination = "C$"
$DesktopDestination = "C$\Users\Public\Desktop"
$ErrorLog = Join-Path $LogPath $ErrorLogName
$InfoLog = Join-Path $LogPath $InfoLogName

Comment: I did this:
`$logFile1 = "test1.log"; $logFile2 = "test2.log"; "Test output" | Out-FileMulti $logFile1,$logFile2`
and it works for me.

Comment: I can't get this to work for the life of me. I ended up using this snippet of code I found- 
%{write-host $_; out-file -filepath $ErrorLog -inputobject $_ -append}

Comment: `Write-Host` can't write to a file. It outputs to the console only. (Unless that's what you want to do...)

Comment: It's a little above my level of PS knowledge, but that snippet of code seems to be indeed outputting to the console as well as the log file.

Comment: That's fine, if that's all you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Tee-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) to accomplish the same thing. Look at example 3 on that page.  Here is a quick sample that grabs the contents of the current directory and saves it to two files.

```
Get-ChildItem | Tee-Object -FilePath teetest.txt | Out-File teetest2.txt
```

Comment: That is one way to do it if you are interested in only two output files.

Answer (score 0):

Found this snippet of code which does what I need-

"Test" | %{write-host $*; out-file -filepath $ErrorLog -inputobject $* -append}