# Output Function Not Working

Tags: powershell, output, powershell-2.0, user-defined-functions

I have functions to output to different multiple locations, like so:

```
Function OutputToInfo
{
        %{
            Write-Host $_; 
            Out-File -FilePath $InfoLog -InputObject $_ -Append
         }
}
```

However, when I run my script and call the function like so:

```
"Script started at: ${TS}" | OutputToInfo
```

it doesn't output to either location. What does get outputted to the console is the function itself-

```
%{
    Write-Host $_; 
    Out-File -FilePath $InfoLog -InputObject $_ -Append
}
```

THIS code works:

```
"Script started at: ${TS}" | %{write-host $_; out-file -filepath $ErrorLog -inputobject $_ -append}
```

But my script looks sloppy with that after every line I want to output to more than one location.

Does anyone know why my function isn't working as intended?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement your own version of [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx). Is that cmdlet not sufficient for your requirements?

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't. I need to write to the console as well as other files (sometimes more than two) simultaneously. I think I'm making some headway though.. Not sure why I have "return" at the very start of my function. Edited OP to reflect new code and new error.

Comment: `Tee-Object` writes to a file and the output stream. That covers your first 2 functions. To write to two files, call `Tee-Object` twice in succession in the pipeline. Or write a function that takes a collection of filenames to write to and loop through that.

Comment: I tried that per my other thread's answers- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641824/piping-to-more-than-one-location-powerscript) but could not get it to work with my script. People suggest other alternatives that do work, like the one I'm using now. I'm just not sure why it won't work in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more of what you are looking for. I would like to point out Alroc's response about [`Tee-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx) is still worth considering.

```
Function OutputToInfo
{
    $input| %{Write-Host $_; Out-File -FilePath $InfoLog -InputObject $_ -Append}
}
```

The $input variable allows a function to access data coming from the pipeline.
http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-functions-filters/

```
"Hello" | OutputToInfo
Hello
```

Also appends "Hello" to file defined earlier by `$InfoLog`

**Given the comments**

There is not native way to handle multiple paths with `Tee-Object` or `Out-File` without some sort of looping structure. So you could be a small function for this. *Caveat*: this is hardly error free and is mostly included to show example of what else could be done.

```
Function Output-ToFiles
{
    Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string]
        $data,
        [parameter(
            Mandatory=$false,
            ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true,
            Position=0)]
        [string[]]
        $paths
    )

    # Write data to console.
    Write-Host "$data"

    # Write data to each file passed. 
    $paths | ForEach-Object{
        $data | Out-File -Append -FilePath $_
    }
}
```

In action

```
PS C:\users\Cameron\Downloads> "DataToPipe" | Output-ToFiles "C:\temp\data.log" "C:\temp\data.log2"
DataToPipe
```

The function accepts pipeline data as a string. The rest of the arguments to the function are stored in the string array `$paths`. For each path with run `Out-File`. Also if you are tired of typing the same path all the time you could just set a default for `$paths` like `$paths = "C:\temp\wood.log`

You could have built a command string with `Tee-Object`s but the logic with this is easier. No need to make it complicated if you do not have to.

Comment: Thank you! One question though- Do you happen to know why **$Error[$Err] | OutputToError** doesn't output the error message to the log file, only the console?

Comment: Not sure at first however your code bite needs more context what is `$err` and the `OutputToError` functions? I dont know for sure since i'm new here but this might border on out of scope for this question as well.